# Two numbers given in certain radix X are (55)X and (64)X. If we add this two numbers, the result is (130)X. What is the radix X?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

Two numbers given in certain radix X are (55)X and (64)X. If we add this two numbers, the result is (130)X. What is the radix X?

hint: Use the polynomial representation to set an equation with x, the radix ans unknown.

just need how to start

Comment: What is the significance of $0$ in the rightmost position of the sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is how to start:**

Solve the equation $\color{red}5x^1+\color{red}5x^0+\color{green}6x^1+\color{green}4x^0=\color{blue}1x^2+\color{blue}3x^1+\color{blue}0x^0$.

**Here is how to continue:**

Solve the equation $x^2-8x-9=0\implies(x+1)(x-9)=0\implies[x=-1]\vee[x=9]$.

Answer (score 1):

If we just look at the last digit,

$$5+4=aX+0$$

Thus $X$ divides $9$. Since the problem uses the digit $6$, we also have

$$X>6$$

The only integer greater than $6$ that divides $9$ is $9$, so $X=9$.

**Check:**

$$(55)_9=5*9+5=50$$
$$(64)_9=6*9+4=58$$
$$(130)_9=1*9^2+3*9+0=108$$

and we indeed have

$$50+58=108$$

So $X=9$ checks.

Answer (score 0):

If a number is $64$ in radix $X$, the number is equal to $6X+4$.  Do the same for the other numbers in the problem and set up an equation.

Comment: I already did --> 4+6x + 5+5x = 3x+x^2 ---> stack here

Comment: OK, you have a quadratic equation for $x$.